# How to concatenate String count and Int

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a set of string count in the form of set and I want to divide it by some int value.

Example:

```
 Counter({'dlr': 21, 'said': 18, 'total': 17, 'bankamerica': 13, 'bank': 11, 'analyst': 9, 'prev': 9, 'februari': 8, 'york': 8, 'would': 8, 'price': 8, 'time': 8, 'wheat': 7})
```

I want to divide it by the some int value so that I will get the word with count divided by that int value.

I am getting TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.

Comment: This is not a set. It's a `collections.counter`, which is more like a dictionary. Also, please post the code that is giving you this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a new counter with a dict comprehension:

```
>>> counter = Counter({'dlr': 21, 'said': 18, 'total': 17, 'bankamerica': 13, 'bank': 11, 'analyst': 9, 'prev': 9, 'februari': 8, 'york': 8, 'would': 8, 'price': 8, 'time': 8, 'wheat': 7})
>>> counter2 = Counter({k:v/2 for k,v in counter.items()})
>>> counter2
Counter({'dlr': 10, 'said': 9, 'total': 8, 'bankamerica': 6, 'bank': 5, 'would': 4, 'price': 4, 'februari': 4, 'york': 4, 'time': 4, 'prev': 4, 'analyst': 4, 'wheat': 3})
```

If you didn't want integer division:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> counter2 = Counter({k:v/2 for k,v in counter.items()})
>>> counter2
Counter({'dlr': 10.5, 'said': 9.0, 'total': 8.5, 'bankamerica': 6.5, 'bank': 5.5, 'prev': 4.5, 'analyst': 4.5, 'would': 4.0, 'price': 4.0, 'februari': 4.0, 'york': 4.0, 'time': 4.0, 'wheat': 3.5})
```

Comment: Its giving TypeError: 'Counter' object is not callable.

Comment: you'll need either `from collections import Counter` or just use `collections.Counter`

Comment: I did both still its giving error. Will you please explain      Counter({k:v/2 for k,v in counter.items()}), so I will find out the solution. I am getting confused in two Counter words.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `Counter = {...}`:

```
for key in Counter.keys():
    Counter[key] /= value
```